# $\frac{\partial W}{\partial x}=g(x+3t)-g(x-t)$. What is the integral of this function with respect to x?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Given

$$\frac{\partial W}{\partial x}=g(x+3t)-g(x-t)$$

How can I compute the integral with respect to x? I have tried to compute this using an indefinite integral of the form:

$$\int_a^x\frac{\partial W}{\partial x}dx$$ I am not able to arrive at the form required which is:

$$W(x,t)=\int_{x-t}^{x+3t}g(\eta)d\eta$$

This form makes sense to me since it is simply a rewrite of the fact that the antiderivative $G$ is evaluated at $x+3t$ and $x-t$. However is this form an antiderivative, a definite integral? I cannot seem to grasp exactly the computation that leads to this form of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_a^xg(y+3\,t)\,dy&=\int_{a+3t}^{x+3t}g(y)\,dy,\\
\int_a^xg(y-t)\,dy&=\int_{a-t}^{x-t}g(y)\,dy.
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\int_a^xg(y+3\,t)\,dy-\int_a^xg(y-t)\,dy&=\int_{a+3t}^{x+3t}g(y)\,dy+\int_{x-t}^{a-t}g(y)\,dy\\
&=\int_{x-t}^{a-t}g(y)\,dy+\int_{a-t}^{a+3t}g(y)\,dy+\int_{a+3t}^{x+3t}g(y)\,dy-\int_{a-t}^{a+3t}g(y)\,dy\\
&=\int_{x-t}^{x+3t}g(y)\,dy+\int_{a-t}^{a+3t}g(y)\,dy.
\end{align}
Since the last integral is a constant (does not depend on $x$), we see that
$$
\int_{x-t}^{x+3t}g(y)\,dy
$$
is in fact a primitive of $g(x+3\,t)-g(x-t)$.

Comment: Very clear. Thank you